# Pop up opening two pages

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a custom button and added a pop up to it. Here's the code

```
<div align="center"><a href="" target="popup" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com','name','width=600,height=400')"><span class="browsebutton13">Google</a></div>
```

It's works perfectly fine on desktop, but on mobile it open two pages.
1st page - The same page on which the button is clicked is opened again
2nd page-  It opens the Google page, which is what I wanted

I want only the second page to be opened when the button is clicked on mobile. I am using Safari browser. It works perfectly fine on desktop.

Comment: because a `<a>` tag opens a link ... try `onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com','name','width=600,height=400'); return false;"`

Comment: Try change href="" to href="javascript:void(0);"

Answer (score 0):

remove the anchor because you already have window.open in your onclick event

Answer (score 0):

```
   <div align="center"><a target="popup" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com','name','width=600,height=400')"><span class="browsebutton13">Google</a></div>
```

remove `href` from above code

### OR

```
 <div align="center"><a href="#" target="popup" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com','name','width=600,height=400')"><span class="browsebutton13">Google</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another (more save) approach would be to change your anchor element to ...

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('http://www.google.com','name','width=600,height=400')">
```

... since this doesn't harm any specs. You only can remove your `href` attribute if you use HTML5 ([docs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-a-element)). Otherwise, the `a` element requires an `href` attribute ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-href)).